# Replicating regular expression in PyMongo that runs in Mongo Shell

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

Trying to match files int he root s3 bucket and not in subfolders for example

https://s3.amazonaws.com/assets.abc.net/ONE.jpg would be a match
and 
https://s3.amazonaws.com/assets.abc.net/SOMEFOLDER/one.jpg will not be a match

In MongoShell if I run this query I get results

```
db.myCollection.find({
"attachments.url" : /https:\/\/s3.amazonaws.com\/assets.abc.net\/[^\/]+\.[A-z]+/
                    })
```

Now in pyMongo, I am trying to replicate the same thing but getting zero results

here is my code

```
regex = re.compile(r"https://s3.amazonaws.com/assets.abc.net/[^/]+\.[A-z]+", re.IGNORECASE)

# AlTERNATE ALSO TRIED
# regex = re.compile(r"https:\/\/s3.amazonaws.com\/assets.abc.net\/[^\/]+\.[A-z]+", re.IGNORECASE)

cursor = db.listings.find({ "attachments.url" : regex })
```

Can someone please help? Python version is 2.7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what ended up working

```
regex = re.compile(r"https:\/\/s3.amazonaws.com\/assets.abc.net\/[^\/]+\.[A-z]+", re.IGNORECASE)

cursor = db.listings.find({ "attachments.url" : { $regex : regex} })
```

Answer (score 0):

```
regex = re.compile(re.escape(r"https://s3.amazonaws.com/assets.abc.net/[^/]+\.[A-z]+"), re.IGNORECASE)


cursor = db.listings.find({ "attachments.url" : regex })
```

try escaping the pattern by [re.escape()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.escape)